# How do I build a wiki into an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, wiki

I want to build an iPhone app that is really a wrapper around a wiki. Specifically, I have some static reference content that can be represented by a hyperlinked set of pages and want to build an app that will provide a nice interface over this content, including search, bookmarking, and annotating. I'm wondering what the best approach is for building something like this.

(I'm spent a fair bit of time googling for answers but pretty much every combination of search terms I can think of returns links to wikis, not links about putting a wiki into an app).

Are there libraries out there for handling wiki content (rendering, navigating links etc.)? I imagine I could just represent my content as a set of local HTML pages and point the web browser control at these but that doesn't seem right. Any ideas on how best to approach this in the iOS world?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at TWedit, it is a wrapper for the excellent TiddlyWiki which is a single file WIKI built around JavaScript and HTML. TW is very powerful and well supported with many plugins available.